# PHP Form submit get the value AND the key from one button with $_POST

Tags: php, json, forms, post

How can I send a key value along with the actual value required on $_POST from one button?

```
<button id='timechange' value='66' key='1' name='subir' type='submit'>Submit</button>

if(isset($_POST['subir'])) {
$change=$_POST['subir'];
$key=....?
}
```

Comment: you need some form to post the value.

Comment: Obviously it has a form, it already works, it just doesn't pass the key as well. I didn't think I needed to post absolutely everything in here.

Comment: _"Obviously it has a form,"_ - No, it's mot obvious. That's why you always need to show us all the relevant code.

Comment: If it didn't have a form it wouldn't work at all and thus my question would be 'why is this not working?' and not the question that I posted. Its also missing <? ?> around the php etc etc. Its ok most people figured that much out and gave good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
<form action="/process.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="1"/>
<button id='timechange' value='66' name='subir' type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

../process.php (you can call it whatever you want, just change the form attr action="your-page.php")

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['subir'])) {
        $change= $_POST['subir'];
        $key= $_POST['key'];
    }
```

Comment: Ok so it needs another field to pass another variable. Thanks that works great.

Comment: @Hasen yeah its that simple...well best of luck

Comment: Well actually its not simple, I'd hoped there would be another way. I thought that the key or index could be sent through from one form action and one button, but it seems its not possible. But thanks for this method, its not too much hassle.

Comment: yes you can send many values at once but it will be much difficult

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have an `<input>` field with the name, value, etc. attributes.

After that, all of this needs to be in a `<form>` that should be submitted with a 'submit' type input element or javascript, so it can be send to the server.

And last, to get the key of an array you can use `key($_POST['subir']);`

Answer (score 0):

The above should work. Have you wrapped the button inside a form?

```
<form name="xxx" id="xxx" action="xx" method="post">
<input name="key" value="x" />
<button id='timechange' value='66' key='1' name='subir' type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>

<?php 
$subir = isset($_POST['subir']) ? $_POST['subir'] : '';
$key = isset($_POST['key']) ? $_POST['key'] : '';
?>
```